# A memory leak happened when using NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I have a memory management question about the use of NSString. Look at the simple code below:

```
NSString *catSeq = [[NSString alloc] init];

for (NSString *cat in cats) {
    catSeq = [catSeq stringByAppendingFormat:cat];
    catSeq = [catSeq stringByAppendingFormat:@"  "];
}

catLabel.text = catSeq;

[catSeq release];   

// This code expresses what all I want to do, but Memory leak happened
// below I delete lines of code to find out the reason

-----------------------------------------------------

NSString *catSeq = [NSString string];

for (NSString *cat in cats) {
    catSeq = [catSeq stringByAppendingFormat:cat];
    catSeq = [catSeq stringByAppendingFormat:@"  "];
}

catLabel.text = catSeq; 

// Memory leak not happened  
-----------------------------------------------------

NSString *catSeq = [[NSString alloc] init];

catLabel.text = catSeq; 

[catSeq release];   

// Memory leak not happened
```

Comment: Why are you doing stringByAppendingFormat, dont you mean stringByAppendingString?

Comment: Also you could directly use :  catSeq = [catSeq stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@[4xspace]",cat];

Comment: @ Jason Kulatunga  YES I could use stringByAppendingString. But problem is still alive.

Comment: Are you profiling this code on a device or the simulator?

Comment: @Chris Gummer  on the simulator

Answer (score 1):

Try this way, autoreleasing.

```
 NSString *catSeq = [[[NSString alloc] init]autorelease];

for (NSString *cat in cats) {
    catSeq = [catSeq stringByAppendingString:cat];
    catSeq = [catSeq stringByAppendingString:@"  "];
}

catLabel.text = catSeq;
```

Comment: Unnecessary to create an instance for nothing.

Comment: @H2CO3 sorry didn't realize that

Comment: H2CO3's comment is completely incorrect; an instance _does_ need to be created, and should be autoreleased. IOW, the original version of this answer would have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

> NSString *catSeq = @"";
>
> for (NSString *cat in cats) {
>
> ```
> catSeq = [catSeq stringByAppendingFormat:cat];
> catSeq = [catSeq stringByAppendingFormat:@"  "];
> ```
>
> }
>
> catLabel.text = catSeq;

Answer (score 0):

use one of these methods

```
 catSeq = [catSeq stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@",cat];
    catSeq = [catSeq stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@",@"  "];
```

or

```
 catSeq = [catSeq stringByAppendingString:cat];
    catSeq = [catSeq stringByAppendingString:@"  "];
```